# MaskedEditExtender number only, remove trailing zeros?

Tags: asp.net, maskededitextender

I have the following ASP.NET code -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="75" />
<ajax:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Mask="999999999" MaskType="Number" PromptCharacter=" " />
```

When I type in "1" and tab out, it displays "100000000". How do I get it to display only "1"? And how do I tweak it so the user can enter any valid positive integers without an upper limit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duh! I need to use the FilteredTextBoxExtender instead of MaskedEditExtender. Here's the code -

```
 <ajx:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                    FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="TextBox1" />
```

The whole time I thought I was using the FilteredTextBoxExtender! Oh well.