# How to convert string to decimal in asp:ControlParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box that will take decimal values.
This is the markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLat" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender3" runat="server" MaskType="Number"
    TargetControlID="txtLat" Mask="99\.999999999" AcceptNegative="Left">
</asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

This is the sqlDataSource insertion markup:

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Lat" ControlID="txtLat" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
```

This is the code behind:

```
protected void btnAddOffice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

I need to convert the text in the txtLat textbox to a decimal.
Can I convert it in the Controlparameter?
If I use Convert.ToDecimal() in the code behind, how do I assign it back to the ControlParameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal(txtLat.Text)

Comment: I believe my problem is with the MaskEditExtender.  After I enter values in the text box using the mask 99.99999999, the values are converted into whole numbers. from 99.999999 to 999999999.

Comment: Maybe try FilteredTextBoxExtender...you can find a similar StackOverflow question here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610442/maskededitextender-number-only-remove-trailing-zeros

Comment: The FilteredTextBoxExtender does not have attribute to define the Mask.  I would like to show the user the decimal format that I am expecting, 99.999999.

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... I removed the escape character (\) from the mask 99.999999999.
This was my final markup in case anybody else is having this problem...

```
    <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender4" runat="server" MaskType="Number" 
TargetControlID="txtLong" Mask="99.999999999" AcceptNegative="Left">
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

THanks to all who commented/helped.